# Why is such a big difference between Total memory and Free memory on the GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a GeForce GTX 1070 and using Keras backed by tensorflow. When i load Keras without running any operation on it it is already a lot of GPU memory in use. Why is that? and how can i free it up?

```
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1070
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7845
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 8.00GiB
Free memory: 6.66GiB
```

Comment: Windows itself, as well as most browsers, use the GPU.

Comment: Its always going to have data in the buffer both for whatever is currently being drawn, your desktop environment, in addition to the memory required for actually running the card itself. The details listed show no abnormalities. This is also off topic.

Comment: i noticed that if i add a second card it is exactly the same with exact same memory usage

Comment: I don't know how you're checking this. But, the canonical way to check it is using something like this: `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=gpu_name,memory.total,memory.used,memory.free,temperature.gpu,pstate --format=csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TensorFlow automatically grabs as much GPU memory as it can on startup. This is because it can manage the allocated memory more efficiently that way, and this is what you're seeing here. There's a [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4566) with instructions on how to tell tf to use less than all available memory.

Comment: What do you mean by grabs all it's memory ?  What if we give only portion of the memory to the TF. I'v seen there is a parameters where we can change up to 1. What is this ?

Comment: By default tensorflow tries to allocate all free memory in the GPU using the cuda allocator and then uses an internal allocator to partition it across Tensors. The flags described in the issue let you change this behavior.